# How to make non-linear regression equation with 4 variables?

Tags: linear-regression, nonlinear-analysis

If we use only X and y, we can write y = mx + c equation for linear regression.
But now I have another 2 variables. So now I have 4 variables. Let's think "x, y, z, w" as my 4 variables. How can I write the equation? If we use linear regression, we can use y = mx + c formula. but it will only represent x and y. but I want to incorporate all x, y, z, and w all together in one formula.

What will be the equation?

Comment: Let $t$ to be the dependent variable and $x,y,z,x$  the independent variables. So, very first linear model *could* be $t=A+B x+C y + D z + E w$. For a nonlinear model, what is it ?

Comment: Only you know how the four variables  are related. How do a, b, c and d arise?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I thought when to collaborate with 4 variables, it will not become a linear regression. otherwise, How did you take A, B, C, D, & E. I have a question related to the way we can use to find the value of the B, C, D, & E.

Comment: http://reliawiki.org/index.php/Multiple_Linear_Regression_Analysis

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you so much sir